# How do I make openbox look like the default Ubuntu theme?

Tags: themes, ambiance, openbox

I was trying out `openbox`, the superlightweight window manager, and something that struck me was "Wow, this is downright ugly".

So, how do I install a ambiance theme to make it "fit in" more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I'd like to add a couple of tweaks:

Load the `gnome-settings-daemon` and use `gtk-theme-switch` (this is a package you need to install called `gtk-theme-switch2`) and composition:

Add to your `~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh` the following lines:

```
gnome-settings-daemon &
gtk-theme-switch2 /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/ &
xcompmgr &
```

`gnome-settings-daemon` loads most settings you may have set up in unity, such as font smoothing/argb or something.

`gtk-theme-switch2` loads the Ambiance theme (unity's default theme).

`xcompmgr` is supposed to reduce flickering when switching windows provide shadows for windows (but shadows don't work on the latest version).

With this, openbox will look as good as Unity. Without the performance cost.

Answer (score 5):

First, (if you don't already) install Openbox and themes:

`sudo apt-get install openbox openbox-themes`

Now that you've got `openbox` installed, you need to replace your current window manager with openbox - for Unity 3D, you can't do this, for Unity 2D, do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `openbox --replace`.

Download the theme [from here](http://cl.ly/AWGQ)

Then, open the "Openbox configuration manager".

[image]

select the "Install a new theme" button, navigate to the `.obt` file, then install it.

Select the theme `Ambiance_ob_test`, and your windows should start looking like the default Ambiance theme (as close as you can get them at least).